# Laravel 5 polymorphic relationship with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, polymorphic-associations

### Tables:

**roles**

```
-id
-role
```

**users**

```
-id
-role_id
```

**schools**

```
-id (primary, foreign-references id on users) 
-other attributes
```

**consultancies**

```
-id (primary, foreign-references id on users) 
-other attributes
```

**students**

```
-id (primary, foreign-references id on users) 
-other attributes
```

School, Consultancies and Students are specialization (or generalization?) of users.

In their model class, I am trying to establish polymorphic one-to-one relationship. It seems straight forward if there had not been roles table AND then `role_id` in user table had been string: role.

But with this structure, how do I get the relationships to work?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to make your primary key a foreign key at the same time.